# Exported resources not working with puppet

Tags: ruby, resources, puppet

I've written a module to set up the Prometheus node_exporter (in here called `ni_trending`). Now I need to add all FQDNs of the nodes to a simple file:  So declaring an exported resource makes much sense here. PuppetDB is configured and working.

Here's the declaration, within my `config.pp`:

```
@@node_exporter { "${listen_address}":
  hostname    => $ni_trending::hostname,
  listen_port => $ni_trending::listen_port,
}
```

When the module is applied on the node I get following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on 
SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a 
Resource Statement, Invalid export in Class[Ni_trending]: {} is not a 
resource on node ydixken-dev01.berlin.ni
```

Within the ni_trending module I'm retrieving all collected resources via:

```
Node_exporter <<| |>>
```

What is missing here?

Comment: Your syntax looks fine, though it's suspicious that the resource type name `node_exporter` is used unqualified.  Is it a native type?  Also, are you sure `$listen_address` has a non-empty value? A [mcve] would make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your answer. :-) Do i understand it correctly that the Resource Type Name needs to be a native type?

Comment: No, you can export resources of defined types, too, but if yours is a defined type then I would expect it to be referenced by its fully-qualified name.  At minimum, that's a matter of good style.  You haven't presented enough information for me to judge whether you have a *bona fide* error in that regard.